# Create log files with CRT vbs script

Tags: vbscript, logfiles, secure-crt

I want to run a script that sends some command taking input from an array. For each element of the array I want the print goes to a different log file.

The script I made so far is below but doesn't work. It seems that only stores the print of last command sent.

How would be the correct way to do it please?

```
#$language = "VBScript"
#$interface = "1.0"

crt.Screen.Synchronous = True

Sub Main
  arr = "1,2,3"
  a = Split(arr, ",")

  For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
    crt.Session.Log False 'Turn off log session
    crt.Session.LogFileName = "C:\Users\Path\MyLogfile No." & a(i) & ".log"  'Define log file name
    crt.Session.LogUsingSessionOptions 'Turn on log session

    crt.Screen.Send "some command" & a(i) & ";" & Chr(13)  'Some command sent to each arr element, this part works fine
  Next

  crt.Session.Log False

  'Restore the default log file     
  crt.Session.LogFileName = "C:\Users\myuser\Documents\default.log"
End Sub
```